# Grouping tags in a form with a remove button like the email addresses in gmail with JS

Tags: javascript, html, tags

i have developed for my website a tag system, people can add tags. Someone can add a tag in a form by clicking a button. In that form people will be able to add multiple tags, is there a way to to group the tags like on StackOverflow tags or like the email addresses in gmail, with a X to remove it if needed?

Example in the image:

[image: Example]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not mention using jQuery, nevertheless, I am giving you a quick method that you can use.

Create a textbox, and give it 100% width, and ID it with something like "tag_text". Before the textbox, create a DIV and give it an ID, say `"tags_container"`.

Add an `keyup` (onkeyup for JS) listener and see if the textbox contains the text that matches with your tag requirements.
If yes, create the tag.

```
$('#tag_text').on('keyup',{},function(e){
    if(e.which==8)
    {
        //Check if the TAB key was pressed
        var tag=$('<div class="tag">').appendTo($("#tags_container"));
        var tagText=$('<span class="tagtext">').appendTo(tag).text($('#tag_text').val());
        var tagIcon=$('<span class="tagremove"').appendTo(tag).text('X');

        $(tagIcon).click({},function(e){
            $(this).remove();
            //Reset the textbox text:
            $('#tag_text').val("");
        });
    }
}
```

Give appropriate CSS so that tags have different color.